# UITableView section with UITextFields

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, sections

I am trying for many days now to set and get inputs of `UITextFields` in cells of sections.

In my first view i have go a `UITextField` where I say how many sections I want to have, and when pressing a button, it gives me that sections (with 4 rows) in the `UITableView`.
my problem now is, that I don't get the correct values of each `UITextField`.

for example:

- all sections have 4 textfields
- in the textfields in can write int or float
- when i know the int from textfield 1 and 2, i divide them...

here is my code....

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () 
{
    NSMutableArray *sectionsArray;
    NSMutableArray *rowsArray;
    NSMutableArray *textFieldArray;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [[self myTableView]setDelegate:self];
    [[self myTableView]setDataSource:self];

    sectionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    rowsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"",@"",@"",@"", nil];
    textFieldArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"",@"",@"",@"", nil];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.myTableView reloadData]; 
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. 
}

#pragma mark - Table View

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    int anzahl = [_AnzahlStationen intValue];//from first view...anzahl=quantity of sections

    //adds sections
    do {

        [sectionsArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Palette %lu",sectionsArray.count+1]];

    } while ([sectionsArray count] < anzahl);

    return sectionsArray.count;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return rowsArray.count;
}


-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return  [sectionsArray objectAtIndex:section];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 24)];
        textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gujarati Sangam MN" size:15];
        textField.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

        textField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        textField.tag = 17;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
        textField.delegate = self;
    }

    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:17];

    textField.text = [textFieldArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell; 
}

#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES; 
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    [textFieldArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:textField.text];
}

@end
```

How can I replace the correct UITextField in the correct row?

Comment: You shouldn't be adding the objects to your datasource in the datasource callback ideally. Why not do that in viewDidLoad? Your question is quite difficult to understand what you are asking.

Comment: So, first i should add the sections in the viewdidload?

Comment: Create all section data elsewhere, then your delegate callbacks can retrieve the count that way. In terms of your actual question, I still do not understand

Comment: Ok, what works is: i get so many sections that i want to have... In every section are 4 textfields.how do i get the value or string of the textfields?

Comment: You should be maintaining the data for each UITextField inside an array of an array. E.g. An array containing multiple arrays, where each array represents a section, within each section array, a dictionary that represents the row data. Rather than having 3 separate arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use a datasource similar to this:

```
NSMutableArray *tableViewData = [NSMutableArray array];

[tableViewData addObject:@[ @{@"textfield" : YourTextField} ]];
[tableViewData addObject:@[ @{@"textfield" : YourTextField} ]];
[tableViewData addObject:@[ @{@"textfield" : YourTextField} ]];
[tableViewData addObject:@[ @{@"textfield" : YourTextField} ]];
```

The above code represents `tableViewData`, containing 4 arrays, each array contains one dictionary which will maintain the data for a single cell. In my example I have just used a single key-value pair of a `UITextField`.

You can dynamically create this however you like, and your delegate and datasource methods can read from it. Rather than having 3 separate arrays.

E.g.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
     return [tableViewData count];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[tableViewData objectAtIndex:section] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSDictionary *cellData = [[tableViewData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Create your cell and use the data stored in the dictionary
}
```

By using the above approach, you are able to update this dictionary, and maintain a state for all of your `UITableView` in a single place, and it keeps the code tidy and readable. To access any `UITextField`, just find it in the dictionary in the `UITableView` datasource and delegate methods.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! I will have a look later after work, i need some time to figure this out...

Comment: everything works fine until now, i get my sections with section titles and its numbers, but now i dont understand how i get the values from the textfields and how to save them in the textfield that they dont get lost when scrolling the view.

Comment: You update the text inside the TextField in the NSDictionary, and you read from that in willDisplayCell, this way you won't lose when scrolling.

Comment: Difficult for me to do that! can i do this: textfield.text = cellData; ? Or how do i do that?

Comment: Something like... textfield.text = (UITextField *)[cellData objectForKey:@"textField"].text;